# Accessing UpdateLinks() in COM Object using Python

Tags: python, excel, csv

I am working on automating an Excel file which is linked to certain .csv files. 
Those .csv files are created from a SAS Code which is run every Quarter. 
The files created are timestamped accordingly for example XYZ_201603.csv and XYZ_201606.csv and so on.

I need to update the links on my Excel File so that it automatically changes the link to the file from next quarter. I am trying to do this using Python win32com.client and my code looks like

```
from win32com import Dispatch
xl_app = Dispatch("Excel.Application")
xl_app.Visible = True
xl_app.DisplayAlerts = False
wb = xl_app.workbooks.open(r"C:\Users\XYZ\Desktop\Test\Summary.xlsx")
xl_app.AskToUpdateLinks = False

try:
    wb.UpdateLink(Name=r"C:\Users\XYZ\Desktop\Test\XYZ_201606.csv")

except Exception as e:
    print(e)

finally:
   wb.Close(True)
   wb = None

return True

xl_app.Quit()
xl = None
```

Whenever I run this, I get the following error

```
(-2147352567,'Exception occured.',(0,'Microsoft Excel','UpdateLink method of
Workbook class failed','xlmain11.chm',0,-2146827284),None)
```

Can Somebody tell me what is going wrong here. Also, incase I have multiple links, how do I tell which link needs to be changed to what? Can I pass a dictionary of directories of updated datasets

The code and the approach has been taken from this answer on Stack Overflow

[Update Links in for Excel Spreadsheet Using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41784468/update-links-in-for-excel-spreadsheet-using-python?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: Interesting to see my answer cited! Per [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/workbook-updatelink-method-excel), link source should be an MS Excel link. Consider importing csv data into workbook or saving csv data as Excel spreadsheet. Remember csvs are text files.

Comment: Hi Parfait. I tried doing that but I get the same error !!

Answer (score 1):

If you review the [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.updatelink), it seems that the `UpdateLink` method can be called without any parameters. Therefore this program should work:

```
import win32com.client as win32
xl_app = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Excel.Application")
xl_app.Visible       = True
xl_app.DisplayAlerts = False
wb = xl_app.workbooks.open(r"C:\Users\XYZ\Desktop\Test\Summary.xlsx")

wb.UpdateLink()
wb.Save()
wb.Close()
xl_app.Quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if my solution solves your issue, but I had the same problem and I used LinkSources() and ChangeLink() instead

```
    newSource = r"C:\Users\XYZ\Desktop\Test\XYZ_201606.csv"
    oldSource  = wb.LinkSources()
    wb.ChangeLink(Name = oldSource[0], NewName = newSource, Type = 1)
```

Hope it helps!